# Is ANOVA a valid test for such application?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, causality

**Context:**

Our company sells a product "A" to different region of the world. Our department measure the reliability of the product by measuring the % of product that failed and return by our customers.

In each regions there are a several customers, but the same customer can't be in 2 regions. We measure customers satisfaction rate (= % reliable product) by year, within each region, and then average customers in the same year and region, so we get a total satisfaction rate / year / region.

**Objective:**

We want to assess if the average reliability of the product "A" is the same across regions or if some region are significantly different.

**Method:**

The proposed approach was to use an ANOVA the data below

[image]

**Questions:**

- Is ANOVA a valid test to compare the mean of both this region ?
- If the test is positive (and we reject the null hypothesis: performance Region1 = Region2), is it reasonable to assume there is some causal relationship between the region and the performance?

**EDIT**

To clarify the question, the goal is not to estimate the reliability of each region but to assess if the difference between the average reliability in each region is statistically significant or not.

Comment: Correlation is definitely an indicator of "some causal relationship" - but it cannot by itself determine what that relationship looks like, or what other variables may be involved, hence the credo "correlation does not imply causation".

Comment: You lost useful information when you normalized the counts (number x returns out of n orders) into %'s (esp. if the number of orders vary by region.)

Comment: @dipetkov I agree, and in practice this is the case, especially between customers. Some place bigger orders. The idea of normalizing was to avoid one big customer in a region skewing the number for the entire region. Our goal is to understand the impact of region on the product reliability, independent of a customer individual behavior. I thought averaging the rate would help. Or am I misguided ?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the best way to deal with one big customer placing a very large order and then returning it; depends on the details perhaps. What I was thinking about is that each number of the 10x2 table is estimated with a different precision / has different standard error. (The standard error of a proportion estimate depends on the sample size n.) The ANOVA is not aware of this.

Comment: If the region-specific sample sizes are large, you can use the normal approximation to the binomial, without ignoring the differences in the standard error of the %'s?

Comment: @dipetkov, thank you I understand your comment now, sample size can be different between regions and years and affect variance. So the assumptions of homogeneity of variance might not hold. Having all the detail I could check the numbers, do you know if there are some range or threshold under which the variation would be consider acceptable for such a test ?

Comment: I don't know that there is such a threshold. Why is it important to do ANOVA?

Comment: @dipetkov it's not, I just thought about this test but if something else would work I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I may have misread your question as it seems to be about ANOVA. In your place I would be asking how to estimate the probability of the event (return of an order) over time in the two regions & not bother too much about hypothesis testing.

Comment: @dipetkov, thanks, I'll edit the post to clarify the question.

Comment: Updating the question can help. You could also consider writing a new question. Right now it seems you're trying to solve `<X>` but asked if `<Y>` is a good way to go about it. If your real interest is `<X>`, then the current question appears to be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Be as precise about the actual situation as possible. Also, think about whether you want to assume that the rate of return remains constant throughout the years *and* across the regions, or it's enough to look at whether the rate is the same for both regions even if it might vary from year to year.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you only have 2 regions you want to compare, a t-test will do just fine (when assumptions are verified, otherwise look into Wilcoxon or Mann-Whitney U tests).
2. No t-tests and ANOVA's are not used to get evidence about causal effects.

Comment: Thanks, aren't t-test and ANOVA equivalent when comparing two groups ? Not that t-test does not work. We are interested mainly in the lower performance of 1 region, so the problem could be formulated as Region A vs Rest of the World.

Comment: yes indeed, it is the same :) It just can cause some confusion since ANOVA is actually used for more than 2 groups, but it is indeed right what you say!